Operations Research about formulating a linear programming problem
I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the set-up costs mentioned in the problem
Problem
Simopfi Corp. sells three products which may be manufactured using any of the three machines available. Machines A, B and C are available for 10, 9 and 8 hours per day respectively. The production rate of each machine and unit selling price of each product are given as follows:
Simopfi Corp. sells three products which may be manufactured using any of the three machines available. Machines A, B, and C are available for 10, 9, and 8 hours per day respectively. The production rate of each machine and the unit selling price of each product are given as follows:
[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Machine} & \text{Product 1} & \text{Product 2} & \text{Product 3} \\
\hline
\text{A} & 4 & 2 & 5 \\
\text{B} & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
\text{C} & 5 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\text{Selling Price/Unit} & 125 & 150 & 100 \\
\hline
\end{array}
]
Note: Production rates of each machine must be taken independently of one another.

Machine A produces product 1 at a cost of Php40/unit; product 2 at Php50/unit; and product 3 at Php60/unit.
Machine B produces product 1 at a cost of Php50/unit; product 2 at Php45/unit; and product 3 at Php50/unit.
Machine C produces product 1 at a cost of Php55/unit; product 2 at Php45/unit; and product 3 at Php55/unit.

Furthermore, an additional machine set-up cost of Php400, Php600, and Php900 is incurred if any machine is used to manufacture product 1, 2, or 3 respectively on a given workday.
Machine set-up costs are only incurred if production of a certain product takes place on that particular machine. Otherwise, no set-up cost is incurred. Assume that machine set-up times (time required to set up a machine to manufacture a certain product) are negligible. Furthermore, assume that production quantities are integer values. The company wishes to determine the production level for each product that will meet a daily requirement of 3,000, 2,500, and 2,000 units for product 1, 2, and 3 respectively, and at the same time maximize net profit.
What My Solution is looking at
Decision Variable:
Let Xij = Amount of product i to be manufactured by machine j such that
i = 1,2,3
j = A,B,C
Objective Function:
Z = Total Profit
Max Z = 125(X1A+X1B+X1C) +150(X2A+X2B+X2C)+100(X3A+X3B+X3C)-(40X1A+50X1B+55X1C)-50(X2A+45X2B+45X2C)-(60X3A+50X3B+55X3C)-400(X1A+X2A+X3A)-600(X1BX2B+X3B)-900(X1C+X2C+X3C)
Im not sure if the italicized and bolded text in the objective function is written properly? I really dont understand how should I make the set-up costs in formulating it? I was thinking of doing a Max min where you max = min { } = w
Then max = w since my professor told me that setup costs require doing that max min problem but I dont know how and I'm not sure if that is applicable on this.

Use a binary variable for each combination of product and machine to indicate whether production of that product occurs on that machine (variable = 1) or not (variable = 0). Use those binary variables in the objective function to assess setup charges. Add constraints that say you cannot produce a particular product on a particular machine unless the corresponding binary variable is 1.
